# Can the class member can be changed depending on the template args in c++

Tags: c++, c++98

I want the class member can be changed depending on the template args.
I want something like follow

```
template<int value>
class MyClass
{
public:
   void print()
   {
      // using the member
      std::cout << sizeData() << std::endl;
      for (int i=0;i<sizeData();i++)
      {
         std:cout << data[i] << std::endl;
      }
   }
   static int sizeData()
   {
     #if value == 1
        return 3;
     #endif
     #if value == 2
        return 6;
     #endif
   }
   static int sizeArray()
   {
     #if value == 1
        return 40;
     #endif
     #if value == 2
        return 200;
     #endif
   }
private:
   #if value == 1
      int data[3];
      const static int array[40];
   #endif
   #if value == 2
      int data[6];
      const static int array[200];
   #endif
}
```

I do not know can it be implemented in c++.

Thanks for your time.

#### add

Many sir already give the answer in C++11 and C++17. Thanks all your's advises.

If the code can be settled in C++98, it will be perfect. Because my code should run on a platform which only support C++98.

Comment: [Template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)?

Comment: What version of C++ are you using?

Comment: I am now using the C++98.

Comment: @XuHui Are you stuck with C++98?

Comment: The bad thing is I must using c++98,  my code should run on a computer which not support c++11.

Comment: @NathanOliver I am write the code for high performance computing applications, I want project run on the Sunway TaihuLight Super Computer (Top3 computer in the world). However, it do not support C++11 yet, and the administrator said not sure when will the platform support C++11. In order to use the computer, I must to write in the C++98.

Comment: In that case you have to use template specialization.

Comment: @freakish Sir, could you please give me a code example about template specialization? I already read your link, but still in confuse. Sorry for my stupid.

Comment: @XuHui I've just posted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) to pick which member you would like to have like

```
template<int value>
class MyClass
{
public:
   static int sizeData()
   {
       return (value == 1) ? 3 : 6; // needs to be improved
   }
   static int sizeArray()
   {
       return sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);  // size of array divided by size of element is then number of elements in the array
   }
private:

   std::conditional_t<value == 1, int[3], int[6]> data;
   const static std::conditional_t<value == 1, int[40], int[200]> array;

};
```

---

While `std::conditional` is not a part of C++98, it's implemented only using C++98 C++, so you can make you own using the possible implementation from the reference site link. You can see that working with

```
#include <iostream>

template<bool B, class T, class F>
struct conditional { typedef T type; };
 
template<class T, class F>
struct conditional<false, T, F> { typedef F type; };

template<int value>
class MyClass
{
public:
    static int sizeData()
    {
       return (value == 1) ? 3 : 6; // needs to be improved
    }
    static int sizeArray()
    {
       return sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
    }
private:

    typename conditional<value == 1, int[3], int[6]>::type data;
    const static typename conditional<value == 1, int[40], int[200]>::type array;

};

int main()
{
    MyClass<1> m;
    std::cout << m.sizeData();
}
```

in this [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b87ecc4db01dbea6).

---

This kind of falls apart for `sizeData` since `data` is not `static` but the function is.  To avoid code duplication, instead of using `std::conditional`, we can use the enum trick to get compile time constants for the sizes of the array and use that like

```
#include <iostream>

template<int value>
class MyClass
{
public:
    static int sizeData()
    {
       return data_size; // now improved
    }
    static int sizeArray()
    {
       return array_size;
    }
private:
    enum { data_size = (value == 1) ? 3 : 6 }; // this is required to be a compile time constant
    enum { array_size = (value == 1) ? 40 : 200 }; // these need to become before the array members
    int data[data_size]; // less verbose
    const static int array[array_size];
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<1> m;
    std::cout << m.sizeData();
}
```

Comment: Sir, thanks for your answer. This way seems will be a little verbose if the value can be 1,2,3,4,5...

Comment: Very nice answer for old C++.

Comment: @XuHui Almost any solution is going to be verbose.  That's one of the main downsides to "old" C++.  C++11 and newer have made this much easier to do as they had years of understanding how we actually use, and want to use the language.

Comment: @NicolBolas Good catch, missed that it wasn't static.  I've updated the code with a bad fix for right now.  I need t put more time into thinking of a better wok around that's C++98 compliant, or at least can be done with C++98 techniques.

Comment: @XuHui I've updated the answer with another solution using enums to try and make it less verbose.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the conditional logic to a localized place. `static inline constexpr` variables are your friends here, if C++17 is an option:

```
template<int value>
class MyClass
{
private:
   inline static constexpr int data_size = (value == 1) ? 3 : 6;
   inline static constexpr int array_size = (value == 1) ? 40 : 200;

public:
   static int sizeData() { return data_size; }
   static int sizeArray() {return array_size; }

private:
      int data[data_size];
      const static int array[array_size];  
};
```

If the logic for computing the size needs to be more complicated, you can always write a `constexpr` function to compute it given a `value` as a (non-template) parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Since you deal with C++98 then you have to use [template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization):

```cpp
template<int value>
class MyClass
{
};

template<>
class MyClass<1>
{
public:
   int sizeData()
   {
       return 3;
   }

   int sizeArray()
   {
       return 40;
   }
private:
   int data[3];
   const static int array[40];
};

template<>
class MyClass<2>
{
public:
   int sizeData()
   {
       return 6;
   }

   int sizeArray()
   {
       return 200;
   }
private:
   int data[6];
   const static int array[200];
};

template<int value>
class Child : public MyClass<value>
{
public:
    int calc()
    {
        // will only work and compile for value 1, 2
        return this->sizeData() + this->sizeArray();
    }
};
```

Comment: sir, if the class exist some member that call the specialization part, where should the methods be placed? I try follow:
template<int value>
class MyClass
{ 
public:
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << sizeData() << std::endl;
    }
}; but the code can not be compiled.

Comment: @XuHui Each specialization should have a distinct `print()` method. Anything shared between specialization you can put in a common base class.

Comment: So if there exist 10 methods like print, which using the specialization, I should copy the same code 10 times into each specialization? It will lead to a lot of redundancy.

Comment: @XuHui for non-static members you can do an inheritance trick (I've updated the answer). For static members you can add a standalone templated function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `if constexpr` and immediately evaluated `constexpr lambdas`.

**Disclaimer**: it is C++ 17 only, need extra brackets that enclose the lambda in order to compile, and I really wouldn't recommend to use this code as it is. It's purpose is **demonstration only**!

```
template<int value>
class MyClass
{
public:
   static int sizeData()
   {
     if constexpr(value == 1)
        return 3;
     
     if constexpr (value == 2)
        return 6;     
   }
   static int sizeArray()
   {
     if constexpr (value == 1)
        return 40;
     
     if constexpr (value == 2)
        return 200;
   }
private:
    int data[([](int v) constexpr { if (v == 1) return 3; if (v==2) return 6; }(value))];
    const static int array[([](int v) constexpr { if (v == 1) return 40; if (v==2) return 200; }(value))]; 
};

int main()
{
   MyClass<1> m1;
   MyClass<2> m2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of C++17 you can use [`constexpr if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If)

```
template<int value>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : data() {}

    static constexpr int sizeData() {
        if constexpr (value == 1) { return 3; }
        else if constexpr (value == 2) { return 6; }
        else { return 1; } // default value is '1'
    }
    
    static constexpr int sizeArray() {
        if constexpr (value == 1) { return 40; }
        else if constexpr (value == 2) { return 200; }
        else { return 10; } // default value is '10'
    }
private:
   int data[sizeData()];
   const static int array[sizeArray()];
};
```

If using e.g. C++14, you could implement custom value traits that maps, at compile time, a given `int` value to another named (`int`) constant, and use these value traits within the class template:

```
template<int value>
constexpr int ValueToDataSizeMapping = 1; // default is '1'

template<>
constexpr int ValueToDataSizeMapping<1> = 3;

template<>
constexpr int ValueToDataSizeMapping<2> = 6;

template<int value>
constexpr int ValueToArraySizeMapping = 10; // default is '10'

template<>
constexpr int ValueToArraySizeMapping<1> = 40;

template<>
constexpr int ValueToArraySizeMapping<2> = 200;

template<int value>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() : data() {}
private:
   int data[ValueToDataSizeMapping<value>];
   const static int array[ValueToArraySizeMapping<value>];
};
```

Answer (score -4):

No this can't be implemented in c++. A precompiler "if" can be evalueted over a runtime variable.

You can declare an `std::vector` to solve this. In this way you can initialize it with the value passed as argument.

At this point the size array and size data function does not need precompiler "if", but just a simple if-else statement.

Comment: This answer appears to be wrong considering there are several other answers that all show how this is totally doable in C++.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The #if statements were illustrative to express what OP would like to achieve using templates.